# how to pass entire model (with data) from view to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know, it may be silly question but now I trying to find the way to solve this. I need return entire model information (data) to controller even though some of the model properties are not using in the view. but I need them in controller action. example id, lable value.

### Example

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, 
        Model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, new { @class = "control-label mandatory" })
 </div>
```

from above first time I am able to see label with property value like `Abstract Title (in English)`. after submitting to controller I am not getting that value in controller model.. If return to same view from controller.

I can see only property namel ike this `AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel`, not its value. That means value of property not storing in the model when passing to controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(MeetingAbstract meetingAbstract)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        { // re-render the view when validation failed.
            return View(meetingAbstract);              
        }           
    }
```

How to handle this without using `@Html.HiddenFor`?. because I have lots of lables I want show.

Comment: the only way to tie data to the model is use an editable field (or the hiddenfor).  displayfor and labelfor don't pass the value tied to them back to the controller

Comment: @MattBodily: can you give example?

Comment: Much better to have a ViewModel that can (re)fetch that data server-side.

Comment: To expand on what @MattBodily said, the only values sent back to the controller are those that are form `<input>` elements, which `HiddenFor` and `EditorFor` generate. `LabelFor` and `DisplayFor` do not generate form `<input>` elements

Comment: as per @jmoerdyk, you need input elements for anything you want posting back. A nice simple way of achieving this (instead of having to write out @Html.HiddenFor(model.PropertyName) for each property you need posting back) is to decorate all the properties that you want to be posted, but don't want to be visible in the view, with the [HiddenInputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and use this in conjunction with a simple EditorForModel html helper in your view and that will take care of rendering all required hidden inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, to my best understanding of your needs from the question, you may have to add Data annotations on your models.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Abstract Title")]
        public string AbstractTitleInEnglish { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data annotation ([DisplayName("Abstract Title"]) will serve as a display text for your label. And when you use your helper method like below, label text will be displayed with "Abstract Title" regardless of post or get.

You have to use your helper method like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, new { @class = "control-label mandatory" })
```

Answer (score 0):

An HttpPost action will put whatever properties you give it into meetingAbstract.  If you want to pass extra properties back to the View you'll have to get them from the database.  That means you need the ID or something to select the correct row.  If you have the ID, then you can do

```
meetingAbstract = db.MeetingAbstracts.Find(meetingAbstract.id);
return View(meetingAbstract);
```

Answer (score 0):

Html.LabelFor does not create an input control which is required to post data back to the controller.  It makes me wonder why you need those back in the post method.  Have you looked into using the UpdateModel method in the post method which applies properties received in the post to the object you pass to this method, while leaving other properties unchanged.  So you can get the object from your database and call UpdateModel to just update the values gotten back.

If that's not the case then you will have to generate hiddens to get the property values back.